# How can I add a "select all" to a facebook Request dialog?

Tags: php, facebook, dialog, request, multi-friend-selector

I use a Request dialog on my Facebook game for my user to invite others to it. So far it works perfect but I miss the possibility to select all friends at once.

I have read the past days that the facebook-dialog isn't providing this feature at all but I saw in many games that there are solutions but I don't know how they so this. If I look e.g. at cityville or castleville then it seems they have createed their own invitation-dialog. I know there is a way to read the friendlist so I could create a select dialog by myself but how can I send the invitation then without using Request Dialog? Or is any other solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can make your own "select friends" dialog by using the graph api to get all the user's friends. When they submit this form, you'll get the user's selected ids and pass them to the request dialog. (See the "Send a Request to One or more users" on [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/).)

Comment: but this can be send only to users that have already used that app. "App to User Requests can be used to re-engage a user in your app and can only be sent to users that have installed the app. For example, notifying a user that something has changed since their last visit, "10 of your friends are now online"."  I want to invite new users to my app so I can't use this. Usually here you can use the request dialog but here you have no feature of "select all"

Comment: @computermaus: You're right. I shouldn't stay up late answering SO questions. I edited my original answer. You can pass an array of uids to the Request Dialog.